# optimize R code for min() and sample() by group

Tags: r, optimization, data.table, lapply

I generate a network with npeople(=80), ncomp(=4) components and I want each component to have density equal to dens(=0.2).

I want to optimize 2 lines of the code which take most of the time (especially if I want to have 5k people in the network).

the 2 lines are:

```
# adjust probability to keep density
nodes[,p:= as.numeric(min(c(1, p * (1/(mean(nodes$p) / c.dens))))), by = c("ID","ALTERID")]

# simulate edges
nodes[, edge := sample(c(0,1),1, prob = c(1-p,p)), by = c("ID","ALTERID")]
```

I have tried using the lapply() function, but the execution time increased - see below the line of code:

```
nodes[,lapply(.SD, function(p) min(c(1, p * (1/(mean(nodes$p) / c.dens))))), by = c("ID","ALTERID")]
```

```
rm(list=ls())
library(data.table)
library(intergraph)
library(igraph)
library(Matrix)
library(profvis)
library(ggplot2)

draw.var <- function(n, var1, rho, mean){
  C <- matrix(rho, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
  diag(C) <- 1
  C <- chol(C)
  S <- rnorm(n, mean = mean)
  S <- cbind(scale(var1)[1:n],S) 
  ZS <- S %*% C
  return(ZS[,2])
}

set.seed(1123)

profvis({

    # create empty list to store data
    dt.list <- list()
    npeople <- 500
    dens <- .2
    OC.impact <- FALSE

    cor_iv_si <- .6
    cor_iv_uc <- 0
    cor_uc_oc <- 0.6
    ncomp <- 4 

    beta_oc <- 2   # observed characteristics 
    beta_uc <- 2   # unobserved characteristics 
    beta_si <- 1 


    # create data.table
    dt.people <- data.table(ego = 1:npeople)

    # draw observed characteristics 
    dt.people[, OC :=  abs(rt(npeople,2))]

    # draw unobserved variable
    dt.people[, UC := draw.var(npeople, dt.people$OC, rho = cor_uc_oc,mean = 5)]

    # set component idientifier
    dt.people$group <- cut_number(dt.people$UC, ncomp,labels = F)

    for(q in 1:ncomp){

      # subset comp
      dt.sub <- dt.people[group == q]

      # create undirected graph
      nodes <- as.data.table(t(combn(dt.sub$ego, 2)))
      setnames(nodes,c("ID","ALTERID"))

      # add attributes
      nodes <- merge(nodes,dt.people[,list(ID = ego, ID.UC = UC, ID.OC = OC)], by = "ID")
      nodes <- merge(nodes,dt.people[,list(ALTERID = ego, ALTERID.UC = UC, ALTERID.OC = OC)], by = "ALTERID")

      # calculate distance
      nodes[,d := abs(ID.UC - ALTERID.UC)]

      # estimate the appropiate density per component
      n.edges <- (dens * (npeople * (npeople - 1)))/ncomp
      n.nodes <- npeople/ncomp
      c.dens <- n.edges/(n.nodes * (n.nodes - 1))

      # estimate initial probability of tie based on distance
      coefficient <- log(c.dens / (1 - c.dens))
      alpha <- coefficient / mean(nodes$d)
      nodes[,p := exp(alpha * d) / (1 + exp(alpha * d))]

      # adjust probability to keep density
      nodes[,p:= as.numeric(min(c(1, p * (1/(mean(nodes$p) / c.dens))))), by = c("ID","ALTERID")]

      # simulate edges
      nodes[, edge := sample(c(0,1),1, prob = c(1-p,p)), by = c("ID","ALTERID")]

      # keep the edges
      nodes <- nodes[edge == 1,list(ID,ALTERID)]

      # bind the networks 
      if(q == 1){
        net <- copy(nodes)
      } else{
        net <- rbind(net,nodes)
      }

    }

    # create opposide direction
    net <- rbind(net,net[,list(ID = ALTERID, ALTERID = ID)])
  })
```

Comment: `as.numeric(runif(1)<p)` should be much faster than `sample()`.  If possible, vectorizing (`as.numeric(runif(N)<p)`) would help a lot more

Comment: Why are you keep calculating `mean(nodes$p)` by group? Should calculate it once and store in variable. Also,  `p * (1/(mean(nodes$p) / c.dens)))` doesn't seem to be group related so could be probably calculated at once. You probably could just do `pmin(c(1, p * (1/(mean(nodes$p) / c.dens))))` altogether- no need in neither the `by` statement or the `as.numeric` one. I don't really have time to test though- just  thought.

Comment: @DavidArenburg when looking into ```mean(nodes$p)``` it actually provides different results if you assign it outside of the group statement. That is, it is recursive as the update-by-reference is available to the ```mean(nodes$p)``` as the groupings are done. I would assume OP actually wants your recommended approach as opposed to the current code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This incorporates @BenBolker and @ DavidArenburg's suggestions and also incorporates some of `data.table`'s tools.

#### Non-Equi joins

The OP code loops through each group. One part of the code also uses `combn` and multiple joins to get the data in the right format. Using non-equi joins, we can combine all of those steps in one `data.table` call

```
  dt_non_sub <- dt.people[dt.people, 
                          on = .(ego < ego, group = group), 
                          allow.cartesian = T, 
                          nomatch = 0L,
                          .(group, 
                            ALTERID = i.ego, ID = x.ego, 
                            ID.UC = UC, ID.OC = OC, 
                            ALTERID.OC = i.OC, ALTERID.UC = i.UC,
                            d = abs(UC - i.UC)) #added to be more efficient
                          ]
  # dt_non_sub[, d:= abs(ID.UC - ALTERID.UC)]
```

#### Vectorization

The original code was mostly slow because of two calls with `by` groupings. Since each call split the dataframe in around 8,000 individual groups, there were 8,000 functions calls each time. This eliminates those by using `pmin` as suggested by @DavidArenburg and then uses `runif(N)<p` as suggested by @BenBolker. My addition was that since your final result don't seem to care about `p`, I only assigned the `edge` by using `{}` to only return the last thing calculated in the call.

```
  # alpha <- coefficient / mean(nodes$d)
  dt_non_sub[,
             edge := {
               alpha = coefficient / mean(d)
               p = exp(alpha * d) / (1 + exp(alpha * d))
               p_mean = mean(p)
               p = pmin(1, p * (1/(p_mean / c.dens)))
               as.numeric(runif(.N)<p)
               }
             , by = .(group)]
  
  net2 <- rbindlist(dt_non_sub[edge == 1, .(group, ALTERID, ID)],
                dt_non_sub[edge == 1, .(group, ID = ALTERID, ALTERID = ID)]
```

One thing to note is that the vectorization is not 100% identical. Your code was recursive, each split updated the `mean(node$p)` for the next `ID, ALTERID` group. If you need that recursive part of the call, there's not much help to make it faster.

In the end, the modified code runs in 20 ms vs. the 810 ms of your original function. The results, while different, are somewhat similar in the total number of results:

**Original**:

```
net
        ID ALTERID
    1:   5      10
    2:  10      14
    3:   5      25
    4:  10      25
    5:  14      25
   ---            
48646: 498     458
48647: 498     477
48648: 498     486
48649: 498     487
48650: 498     493
```

**Modified**

```
net2
       group ALTERID  ID
    1:     2       4   3
    2:     2       6   4
    3:     4       7   1
    4:     4       8   7
    5:     2       9   4
   ---                  
49512:     3     460 500
49513:     3     465 500
49514:     3     478 500
49515:     3     482 500
49516:     3     497 500
```